# Postgresql how to calculate max of a count()

Tags: postgresql, max

I m trying to find out a way to calculate max of count(r.customer_id). When running the script there are 4 values with the same highest value, so what I need to produce is a table with these 4 values

```
SELECT     c1.customer_id, c1.first_name, c1.last_name, count(r.customer_id)
FROM       customer c1 
INNER JOIN rental r 
ON         (c1.customer_id = r.customer_id)  
WHERE      r.staff_id = 2 
GROUP      BY c1.customer_id, c1.first_name, c1.last_name
ORDER BY   4 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name, count 
      FROM (
      SELECT c1.customer_id as customer_id, c1.first_name as first_name, c1.last_name as last_name, count(r.customer_id) as count
      FROM customer c1 
      INNER JOIN rental r ON ( c1.customer_id = r.customer_id  )  
      WHERE r.staff_id = 2 
      GROUP BY c1.customer_id, c1.first_name, c1.last_name
    ) x 
    GROUP BY customer_id, first_name, last_name
    HAVING count = max(count)
    order by 4 desc
```

Comment: thank you for your immediate response, when i run your script it says: ERROR:  argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type bigint
LINE 9:     ) x HAVING max(count)
                       ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type bigint
SQL state: 42804
Character: 392

Comment: ye, it should be a condition, I've edited the answer

Comment: Now i get: ERROR:  column "x.customer_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1:  SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name, count 
                ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "x.customer_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 9